# Pandas Replace not producting required output

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas replace is not working for me, below is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Curve' : ['RTY-USDSwapZero','SX7E-EURSwapZero'], 'Values' : [1,1]})
```

I tried :

```
df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True)
df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)
df.Curve.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)
df = df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'})
```

etc.. all the combinations

---

```
df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)
print (df)
```

Comment: for me second working well.

Comment: My pandas version is 0.24.2, which one are you using?

Comment: It is not replacing for me

Comment: In sample data? Can you show `print (df)` after `df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)` ?

Comment: try `df.replace(['USDSwapZero', 'EURSwapZero'], value=['USD', 'EUR'], inplace = True, regex = True)` (I have also pandas=0.24.2)

Comment: Edited answer for test, can you add `print (df)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working well your second solution, there is `inplace=True`, so no assign:

```
df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)
print (df)
      Curve  Values
0   RTY-USD       1
1  SX7E-EUR       1
```

But seems solution should be simplify by replace `SwapZero` to empty string:

```
df.replace('SwapZero','',inplace = True,regex = True)

print (df)
      Curve  Values
0   RTY-USD       1
1  SX7E-EUR       1
```

---

Also I think `inplace` is not good practice, check [this](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace) and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529), so you can assign back:

```
df = df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'}, regex = True)
#df = df.replace('SwapZero','', regex = True)
print (df)
      Curve  Values
0   RTY-USD       1
1  SX7E-EUR       1
```

Comment: Thanks,df.replace('SwapZero','', regex = True) worked for me! For some reason first is not working

Comment: @DhruvMahajan - Super, glad can help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of`replace`:

> regex : bool or same types as `to_replace`, default False
> Whether to interpret `to_replace` and/or `value` as regular
> expressions. If this is `True` then `to_replace` *must* be a
> string. Alternatively, this could be a regular expression or a
> list, dict, or array of regular expressions in which case
> `to_replace` must be `None`.

so for

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Curve' : ['RTY-USDSwapZero','SX7E-EURSwapZero'], 'Values' : [1,1]})
```

theses two options worked for me in pandas=0.24.2

```
df.replace(['USDSwapZero', 'EURSwapZero'], 
           value=['USD', 'EUR'], 
           inplace = True, regex = True)

df.replace(None, 
           value=['USD', 'EUR'], 
           inplace = True, 
           regex = ['USDSwapZero', 'EURSwapZero'])
```

Comment: and `df.replace({'USDSwapZero':'USD','EURSwapZero' :'EUR'},inplace = True,regex = True)` not working for you?